# Using one data.frame to update another

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

Given 2 data frames that are identical in terms of column names/datatypes, where some columns uniquely identify the rows, is there an efficient function/method for one data.frame to "update" the other?

For example, in the following, `original` and `replacement` are identified by `'Name'` and `'Id'`.  `goal` is the result of finding all rows from `replacement` in `original` (by the unique id's) and replacing with `Value1` and `Value2`

```
original = data.frame( Name = c("joe","john") , Id = c( 1 , 2) , Value1 = c(1.2,NA), Value2 = c(NA,9.2) )
replacement = data.frame( Name = c("john") , Id = 2 , Value1 = 2.2 , value2 = 5.9)
goal = data.frame( Name = c("joe","john") , Id = c( 1 , 2) , Value1 = c(1.2,2.2), Value2 = c(NA,5.9) )
```

The solution should work for an `original` and `replacement` of arbitrary length (although `replacement` should never have more rows than `original`).  In practice, I'm using 2 id columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set a unique ID as the row names. Then it is simple indexing:

```
rownames(original) = original$Id
rownames(replacement) = replacement$Id

original[rownames(replacement), ] = replacement
```

Comment: what if there will be rows with equal Id? for ex. you can't do rownames(original) <- c(1,1,1)

Comment: They just have to be unique. For example paste(idvar1, idvar2, ...)

Comment: my fault, arrr. if there are several places in original, and replacement with one Id, than it is unclear from where to where should be replaced

Comment: but there are two identifiers here - Id and Name.  I don't think this approach works for non-integer identifiers

Comment: @SFun28, why this shouldn't? rownames are strings

Comment: It seems that in this example rownames(replacement) returns strings which are coerced to integers which allows original to be subsetted?  What if the identifier is Name?  what does original[ "Joe" , ] do?

Comment: @SFun28 You *can* do the indexing by character. Check out this example: https://gist.github.com/1331778

Comment: @Max Yea definitely not the most robust like you point out, but I like it when I can get away with using it because it's simple and fast.

Comment: +1  That does in fact work.  cool.  R continues to amaze (and slightly scare) me every day. =)

Comment: Yea! It really comes in handy. Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

I'd use `data.table` objects. This code seems to work on your example:

```
library(data.table)

# set keys
original.dt <- data.table(original, key=c("Name", "Id"))        
replacement.dt <- data.table(replacement, key=c("Name", "Id"))

goal2 <- original.dt
# subset and reassign
# goal2[replacement.dt[, list(Name, Id)]] <- replacement.dt
goal2[replacement.dt] <- replacement.dt  # cleaner and faster, see Matthew's comment

goal2 <- as.data.frame(goal2)

identical(goal, goal2) # FALSE, why? See Joris's comment
all.equal(goal, goal2) # TRUE
```

Comment: thanks!  I've avoided a dependency on data.table thus far and would prefer a solution using the base classes.  Will wait for other replies.

Comment: +1 for the data.table. As to why identical returns FALSE: in goal2, Id is an int vector, whereas in goal this is a num vector.

Comment: @JorisMeys ... as `str()` reveals. Thanks!

Comment: Small improvement : can drop the `[,list(Name,Id)]` bit. Just `goal2[replacement.dt]<-replacement.dt` is shorter and faster because `replacement.dt`'s key is already `"Name,Id"`. `i` doesn't have to be keyed, but when it is, it's `i`'s key columns that are joined and a faster merge algorithm is used internally that takes advantage of the fact that both tables are sorted.

Answer (score 6):

Using base R, you can use the function `replace.df()` below, which is loosely based on the source code of `merge.data.frame()`. Contrary to some other solutions, this one allows multiple columns for identification. I use it rather often in my job. Feel free to copy and use.

This function controls for cases where rows in y are not found in x. Mind that the function does not check whether the combinations are unique. match() will only replace the first occurence by the first occurence of a combination.

The function is used as follows :

```
> replace.df(original, replacement,by=c('Name','Id'))
  Name Id Value1 Value2
1  joe  1    1.2     NA
2 john  2    2.2    9.2
```

Note that this effectively detects the writing error you have in your original code. `replacement` contains a variabe named 'value2' (small v) instead of Value2 (capital V). After correcting this, the result becomes:

```
> replace.df(original, replacement,by=c('Name','Id'))
  Name Id Value1 Value2
1  joe  1    1.2     NA
2 john  2    2.2    5.9
```

You can use that function as well for changing the values in only some of the columns

```
> replace.df(original, replacement,by=c('Name','Id'),cols='Value2')
  Name Id Value1 Value2
1  joe  1    1.2     NA
2 john  2     NA    5.9
```

The function:

```
replace.df <- function(x,y,by,cols=NULL
           ){
    nx <- nrow(x)
    ny <- nrow(y)

    bx <- x[,by,drop=FALSE]
    by <- y[,by,drop=FALSE]
    bz <- do.call("paste", c(rbind(bx, by), sep = "\r"))

    bx <- bz[seq_len(nx)]
    by <- bz[nx + seq_len(ny)]

    idx <- match(by,bx)
    idy <- match(bx,by)
    idy <- idy[!is.na(idy)]

    if(is.null(cols)) {
      cols <- intersect(names(x),names(y))
      cols <- cols[!cols %in% by]
    }

    x[idx,cols] <- y[idy,cols]
    x
  }
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to say "you don't HAPPEN".  fixed the post.

Comment: @SFun28 : ah no, but I maybe should start doing that stuff. I also corrected a typo (the drop=FALSE in the last lines was obviously erroneous. I'm not that good in reproducing functions from the top of my head...)

Comment: @TylerRinker : Did you see my correction? The drop=FALSE in the second last line is rubbish and should be removed. It is not an argument for the assignment function. I typed the function from the top of my head, the original is at work. Hence the mistake.

Comment: @Joris Now it works with everything except: `cols='Value2'` which throws up the warning `Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp, idx, cols, value = NULL) : replacement has length zero`

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using the `digest` package.

```
library(digest)
# generate keys for each row using the md5 checksum based on first two columns
check1 <- apply(original[,1:2], 1, digest)
check2 <- apply(replacement[,1:2], 1, digest)

# set goal to original and replace rows in replacement
goal <- original
goal[check1 %in% check2,] <- replacement
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it suffers in terms of performance.  You need to calculate the digest which would be slower than simply concatenating the identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

```
# limit replacement to elements that have a correspondence in original 
existing = replacement[is.element(replacement$Id, original$Id),]
# replace original at positions where IDs from existing match   
original[match(existing$Id,original$Id),]=existing
```

Comment: Eh, the is.element generalizes easily (just ANDing the index arrays for both), but I can't see a straightforward way for the match part.

Answer (score 1):

```
require(plyr)
indexes_to_replace <- rownames(match_df(original,replacement,on='Id'))
indexes_from_replace<-rownames(match_df(replacement,original,on='Id'))
original[indexes_to_replace,] <- replacement[indexes_from_replace,]
```

param `on` of function `match_df` can take vectors as well.

Comment: This is similar to John Colby's answer, but I think a little slower because of the call to match_df?

Answer (score 1):

I produced a function that uses the method of indexing (see answer by John Colby above).  Hopefully it can be useful for all such needs of updating one data frame with the values from another data frame.

```
update.df.with.df <- function(original, replacement, key, value) 
{
    ## PURPOSE: Update a data frame with the values in another data frame
    ## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## ARGUMENT:
    ##   original: a data frame to update,
    ##   replacement: a data frame that has the updated values,
    ##   key: a character vector of variable names to form the unique key
    ##   value: a character vector of variable names to form the values that need to be updated
    ## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## RETURN: The updated data frame from the old data frame "original". 
    ## ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    ## AUTHOR: Feiming Chen,  Date:  2 Dec 2015, 15:08

    n1 <- rownames(original) <- apply(original[, key, drop=F], 1, paste, collapse=".")
    n2 <- rownames(replacement) <- apply(replacement[, key, drop=F], 1, paste, collapse=".")

    n3 <- merge(data.frame(n=n1), data.frame(n=n2))[[1]] # make common keys
    n4 <- levels(n3)[n3]                # convert factor to character

    original[n4, value] <- replacement[n4, value] # update values on the common keys
    original
}
if (F) {                                # Unit Test 
    original <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c(10, 20, 30))
    replacement <- data.frame(x=2, y=25)
    update.df.with.df(original, replacement, key="x", value="y") # data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), y=c(10, 25, 30))

    original <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), w=c("a", "b", "c"), y=c(10, 20, 30))
    replacement <- data.frame(x=2, w="b", y=25)
    update.df.with.df(original, replacement, key=c("x", "w"), value="y") # data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3), w=c("a", "b", "c"), y=c(10, 25, 30))

    original = data.frame(Name = c("joe","john") , Id = c( 1 , 2) , Value1 = c(1.2,NA), Value2 = c(NA,9.2))
    replacement = data.frame(Name = c("john") , Id = 2 , Value1 = 2.2 , Value2 = 5.9)
    update.df.with.df(original, replacement, key="Id", value=c("Value1", "Value2"))
    ## goal = data.frame( Name = c("joe","john") , Id = c( 1 , 2) , Value1 = c(1.2,2.2), Value2 = c(NA,5.9) )
}
```